# How to get selenium to scroll to an element (Typescript)?

Tags: selenium, jestjs, automated-tests

I'm using jest and selenium. I recently ran into an issue where a sticky footer I have is blocking the element I want to click on. I get the error: 'ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (988, 1108)'.

I have tried adding a function =>

```
        this.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView ;", element);
    }
```

but I get this error: 'JavascriptError: javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView  is not a function'.

How do I get selenium to scroll to an element so I can click it using typescript/jest?

Comment: Did you try adding the round brackets `scrollIntoView()`? Moreover, is `element` found using `driver.find_elements` or `driver.find_element`?